# How to get generic field type (string representation) with help reflection - Java?

Tags: java, reflection, types, type-inference

There are some fields:

```
public class Class1 {
    private Map<String,Integer> field1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    private int someField = 1;
    private int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
    private List<ArrayList<String>> words = null;
    private ArrayList<String>[] group = (ArrayList<String>[])new ArrayList[4];
    private List<List<List<ArrayList<List<List<String>>>>>> lists = null;
}
```

Is there a simple way to get string representation of each of these (and generally any) types?

Comment: I suppose you might be able to do it with `TypeToken` from Guava, getting it from the Field instance...

Comment: Perhaps refactor `List<List<List<ArrayList<List<List<String>>>>>> lists` into a separate class or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (Field field : Class1.class.getDeclaredFields())
    System.out.println(field.getGenericType());
```

Output:

```
java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>
int
class [I
java.util.List<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>[]
java.util.List<java.util.List<java.util.List<java.util.ArrayList<java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>>>>
```